# Which lattice-based encryption scheme/signatures is fundamental?

Tags: lattice-crypto, pedagogy

If I would like to focus on only one signature scheme, and only one encryption based on lattices in a pedagogical context (to introduce the concept of lattice-based crypto to people familiar with cryptography)?

Is it possible to consider only one cryptographic problem in this context?

Comment: If you really want to see the lattices, but not go into to much crypto technicalities this is how I introduced it:
https://github.com/lducas/bamenda/blob/master/notes.pdf

Comment: I don't remember the full details of how to formulate this, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but I recall that there is a way to reduce RSA to a problem of finding the "best" lattice basis for a lattice with a fundamental region with volume $N$ (that's the determinant of the basis matrix if I recall). I think it is elementary to see that if $N=pq$ for two primes $p$ and $q$ then the "best" basis for the lattice on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is $\{(p,0), (0,q)\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will only discuss LWE/SIS, but much of what is said could be extended to other assumptions (namely NTRU).

For encryption, the following is (roughly) canonical.
It's also historically important --- it's the (secret key) cryptosystem Regev initially introduced in his paper introducing LWE.

You fix some distribution $\chi$ on $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ (typically $\chi$ being i.i.d. Gaussians, or i.i.d. bounded uniform for simplicity).
The secret is $s\gets \chi$ a draw from this distribution.
To encrypt $m\in\mathbb{Z}_q$, you sample $A\gets \mathbb{Z}_q^n$, then output $(A, b:= As + e + m)$ where $e\gets \chi$.

This doesn't yet yield a correct cryptosystem (decrypting $b - As = m + e\neq m$).
It can be made to be correct by encoding $m$ in an error-tolerant way, for example starting with $m\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ and encoding $m\mapsto (q/p) m\in\mathbb{Z}_q$. This is the cryptosystem Regev suggested (perhaps with $p = 2$), namely

1. $\mathsf{KeyGen}$: sample $s\gets \chi$
2. $\mathsf{Enc}_s(m)$ sample $A\gets \mathbb{Z}_q^n$, $e\gets \chi$, and return $(A, As + e + (q/p)m)$
3. $\mathsf{Dec}_s(A, b)$: Return $\lfloor (b - As) / (q/p)\rceil = \lfloor m + e / (q/p)\rceil$.
   This is equal to $m$ if $|e / (q/p)| < 1/2$, or if $|e| <q / (2p)$.

I say this is roughly canonical as it is a key subroutine in

- both methods of constructing PKE from lattices (random linear combinations of encryptions of zero, and "noisy diffie hellman")
- all constructions of FHE.

in fact, most lattice-based encryption can be seen as doing the above, and

- varying the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}_q$ arithmetic occurs over,
- varying the encoding $m\mapsto (q/p)m$ one works with, or
- applying an aforementioned generic (for lattices) SKE to PKE transformation,
- using an LWR variant instead of an LWE variant (i.e. using "deterministic noise").

---

For signatures, things are a little less simple, because there are (at least) two main approaches to lattice-based signatures, namely

- "Hash and Sign" (or "GPV") signatures, and
- "Fiat Shamir with Aborts" (or "Lyubashevsky") signatures

that *a priori* seem quite different.
They can be presented in a uniform way though, see [theorem 1.4 of this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/915.pdf).

> **Theorem 1.4 (Informal)**. Lattice-based Lyubashevsky signatures using the bit-decomposition Fiat-Shamir
> hash function are equivalent to lattice-based Hash-and-Sign signatures.

So in principle you can uniformly present a single lattice-based identification scheme that you convert into a signature in various ways, namely leading to either Hash and Sign or Fiat Shamir with Aborts signatures.
I won't write as much about this though, as I haven't thought about it as much.